# how to create queries in prometheus with wildcard

Tags: prometheus, metrics, observability

my application emits counter metrics something like this:

```
app_counters_some_client_response_code_201_count_value{}
app_counters_some_client_response_code_400_count_value{}
app_counters_some_client_response_code_404_count_value{}
```

I want to create a graphana dashboard which can show all these different metric values in the same dashboard with the status codes as the legend.. how can I write such a single query using a wildcard as there can be multiple response codes and we don't have the complete list of possible values, so we won't be able to write a different query for each metric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, such metrics are a bad idea for exactly the problem you are having. Please read [recommendations](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/writing_exporters/#metrics) on exposing metrics, and consider changing your metrics to use labels. Something like

```
yourApp_yourScope_responses_total{code="201"}
yourApp_yourScope_responses_total{code="400"}
yourApp_yourScope_responses_total{code="404"}
```

That being said, you could use a query:

```
label_replace({__name__=~"app_counters_some_client_response_code_\d+_count_value"}, "http_code", "$1", "__name__", "app_counters_some_client_response_code_(\d+)_count_value")
```

and specify legend in the Grafana panel as `{{http_code}}`

**Explanation:**
This query:

1. [selector](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#instant-vector-selectors) `{__name__=~"app_counters_some_client_response_code_\d+_count_value"}` gets all time series with name matching regex `app_counters_some_client_response_code_\d+_count_value`
2. Then [`label_replace`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#label_replace) extracts digits from the names of the metrics and puts them into the label `http_code`.